# Robolectric - RuntimeException Stub

Tags: android, robolectric

I have a Robolectric test case written as

```
public void setUp(){
    mActivity = new CalcActivity();
    ShadowActivity shadow = Robolectric.shadowOf(mActivity);

//more code
```

But i'm getting a `RuntimeException : Stub!` at the very start of the setUp method.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
at android.content.Context.<init>(Context.java:4)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.<init>(ContextWrapper.java:5)
at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.<init>(ContextThemeWrapper.java:5)
at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:6)
at com.example.advancedcalc.CalcActivity.<init>(CalcActivity.java:13)
at com.example.CalcActivityTest.setUp(CalcActivityTest.java:25)
```

CalcActivity implements an OnclickListener and it has a bunch of other methods that perform basic calculator operations inside.

Can anyone tell me why i'm getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!` and how to deal with it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you added

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
```

as an annotation to your test class?

Comment: The idiot that I am i just noticed it a few secs before i got your answer. Cant believe i made an entire question for something that dumb. Thanks for your help in any case :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using assertions from `junit.framework.Assert` and changing to `org.junit.Assert` did the trick